# Unable to view html file in new tab inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, azure-blob-storage, window.open

Hi I am working in react application. I am trying to display file in new tab. File source is azure data lake. below is my code.

```
 const config = {        
           path: `/Storage/getsastoken/?storageName=${storage}&containerName=${containerName}`,   
               method: "GET",          
           success: async (url: any) => {      do {
                 const containerURL: ContainerURL = new ContainerURL( url,                
                       StorageURL.newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential()));            
                       const listBlobsResponse = await containerURL.listBlobFlatSegment(Aborter.none, marker);     
                this.marker = listBlobsResponse.nextMarker;
                const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL,reportPath);
                window.open(blockBlobURL.url,"data:text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

I want to open file in new tab but file always downloads rather than opening in  new tab. Not sure any issue with file itself.
Below properties set in file properties in azure storage

[image]

Can someone help me to understand this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Could you please tell me if  the HTML is also downloaded when you copy and paste the URL in the tab?

Comment: Hi Jim, Now what I have did is, On click on button click I am opening sasuri itself and it works fine. So now I understood inside of ajax success call window.open will not work. Is my understanding correct?